# (Unbound Breakpoints) How to debug nestjs project in vscode for nx project

Tags: nestjs, nrwl-nx

I am trying to debug my nestjs application created by NX project in vs code. I added Launch.json file which is look like below. I have two projects in it one is angular and second one is nestjs I want to debug my nestjs project.

```
{  
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach by Process ID",
  "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
},
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Program",
  "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/serve",
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"]
}
```

]
}

Whenever I try to add breakpoints they are become grey in color and shows that they are unbound breakpoints even after pointer goes to the breakpoint still not pause at it. Please help me with any solution.

Comment: Where you able to fix this issue @Suraj

Comment: Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69201036/debugging-a-nestjs-app-in-nx-using-a-vscode-launch-configuration/76431078#76431078

Answer (score 9):

I found a better way that doesn't require me to manually launch the app before hand.

My `launch.json` file:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch my-nest-project",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "node",
            "runtimeExecutable": "npx",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "nx",
                "serve",
                "my-nest-project"
            ],
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/app/my-nest-project"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here change `my-nest-project` to your project name.

Comment: note that with this, you may not be able to pickup .env files from root directory, for that you will need to add   "env-cmd", "-f", "${workspaceFolder}/.env"... args before nx

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was to run the app with `nx serve my-nest-project` then launching VS code debugger with the following launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Attach to nestjs",
            "request": "attach",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/app/my-nest-project",
            "type": "node",
            "port": 9229,
        }
    ]
}
```

The most important part for me was the `cwd` as i had a monorepo workspace so the `cwd` need to point to the root of the nestjs app not the workspace root.

If you need to have more control on the debugging port, you can set it like this `nx serve my-nest-project --port=9223` for example.

Comment: After countless hours of trying different solutions, this is the one that worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the breakpoint that didn't work was in controller. The problem was that the module of this controller wasn't part of the `imports` of the main module that should actually run.

Answer (score 0):

I just change **webpack.config.js** content in my NestJS project with:

```
const { composePlugins, withNx } = require('@nrwl/webpack');
const path = require('path');

// Nx plugins for webpack.
module.exports = composePlugins(withNx(), config => {
  // Update the webpack config as needed here.
  // e.g. `config.plugins.push(new MyPlugin())`
  config.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate = function (info) {
    const rel = path.relative(process.cwd(), info.absoluteResourcePath);
    return `webpack:///./${rel}`;
  };
  return config;
});
```

My **.launch** configuration is:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to NestJS",
      "port": 9229,
      "request": "attach",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
      "type": "node"
    }
    ]
}
```